# Is there a way to get the width of contents in a cell in PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

I am trying set the width of a cell to be the width of the content so there isn't a lot of empty space that happens I have used the following.

`$tmExport->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($courseColumn)->setAutoSize(true);`

So I want to use something like

`$tmExport->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($courseColumn)->setWidth($contentWidth);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I implemented

```
    $cellValue = $tmExport->getActiveSheet()->getCell($courseCell)->getValue(); 
    $width     = mb_strwidth($cellValue);$lastCourseId = end($this->courses)->courseid;

    foreach ($this->courses as $courseItem) {
        if ($courseItem->courseid === $lastCourseId) {
            $tmExport->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($courseColumn)->setWidth($width);
        } else {
            if ($width > $maxWidth) {
                $tmExport->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($courseColumn)->setWidth($maxWidth);
            } else {
                $tmExport->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($courseColumn)->setWidth($width);
            }
        }
    }`
```